# Can I restrict my iPhone app from being used by iPhone3G's?

Tags: iphone, ios

My iphone app doesn't run well on the iPhone 3G. Can I make it so users with these models can't download the app? If so, what does a 3G user see when they search for my app in the app store?

Does it appear in the store at all for them? If it does, when are they notified that they can't download the app?

Comment: An iPhone app that doesn't work well on an iPhone 3G? Did you write OS4.0?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in your info.plist. This lets you tell the App Store exactly which capabilities you require instead of which device you require. 
If your app "doesn't run well" on a 3G I'll guess it is because of performance and therefore you'd want to require a newer processor. Look into setting arm7 as one of your required device capabilities.
For more info look here:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3

Comment: Ok, so if I require armv7, what do non-armv7 users see...

Can they still download my app?
Can they download and open the app?

Answer (score 0):

Make it run better. Or if it's not completely unusable, just let them use it anyway. People with old devices expect them to be a bit slow.

According to the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf]) (which links to the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW10)), you can't prohibit certain devices. You can, however, require certain features which are only present on new devices:

- `armv7` is what I'd recommend (older devices are armv6)
- `magnetometer`, because older devices don't have one. Apple might look at you funny if your app doesn't actually use the compass though.
- `opengles-2`, because older devices only support 1.1. Apple might look at you funny too.
- `auto-focus-camera`, except the iPad and all the iPod Touches don't have one. Probably not what you want.

Comment: Ok, so if I require armv7, what do non-armv7 users see... 

Can they still download my app? 
Can they download and open the app?

How am I able to notify the user that the app does not work for their device?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not shown on the device app store, but it's shown in iTunes (next to a list of supported devices). Apple is unlikely to do this wrong, especially since this has existed for over a year.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 3GS uses iOS 6.1.x so if your app support iOS 7+ it will not be able to install on iPhone 3GS, this is the best possible way to avoid download on that device.

Comment: i know may be it can help others in some understanding