# iPhone 4 only app?

Tags: iphone-4

Is it possible to restrict an app to only run on an iPhone 4?  I know you can have an iPad only app.  And in iTunes Connect you used to be able to indicate an iPhone only app. But now in iTunes Connect it says that to restrict an app to certain devices one can use the Info.plist.  Someone suggested that in the Info.plist if a FrontFacingCamera is required that would restrict it to iPhone 4.  Is this the way to restrict an app to run on only on an iPhone 4?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283189/can-i-restrict-my-iphone-app-from-being-used-by-iphone3gs/3283302#3283302

Comment: Also, if you find answers that give you what you are looking for, you are encouraged to click the check mark next to them. It gives people a warm fuzzy feeling inside, and they are more likely to continue helping you. :)

Comment: why would you want to artificially limit the use of your app to a single type of device?

Comment: Bryan - The reason is that the app is a game with a lot of graphics.  For the iPhone 4 the binary is about 120 MB for the 960x680 display.  If the app also ran on the iPhone 3, I would have to include the compressed graphics for the 320x480 resolution and the code to switch between the two.  Plus the iPhone 3 user would have to download the 120 MB graphics even though they would never use them.  Since I already have the game on the iPhone 3, I figure just make another version for the iPhone 4, and save myself and the users a number of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't do an AppStore restriction. However you can prevent you app from running on non-i4 devices. You can also write so in the app description, saying that you actually need i4 to run this app.

*Sorry if I'm wrong.*

Comment: Of course you can restrict your application to run only with a certain resolution. I suppose that's what Nick means.

Comment: How would you restrict the app so that it can only run with a certain resolution?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to restrict (through resolution) pre-purchase someone from buying. Because that's what this question is about - if on a certain device we want to disallow someone from buying it off the store - or else they'll be mad when they get the software down and find that it doesn't have graphics made for their device (pre-retina graphics, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you can test the `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale` property. As of right this moment, only an iPhone 4 will return a "2" in that property.

You could check that out in your AppDelegate and bellyache appropriately if it appears you're running on unders-spec'ed hardware. Just bear in mind that if the next iPad gets a retina display (or the iPod Touch Steve will almost undoubtedly be announcing next week), that property will be "2" for them as well. But maybe that's ok--if you're supporting the iPhone 4 maybe the new iPod Touch should be supported as well? If it's really about the screen density, then you should test the screen density, not whatever else you can find to identify the device.