# How do I make my application available on the App Store only for iPhone 4 or faster devices?

Tags: app-store, iphone-4, iphone-3gs

My app can't run correctly on 3gs (mostly by performance reasons & no way to fix that).
How I can drop off support for 3gs on the AppStore?

it's related to:
[How do I make my application available on the App Store only for iPhone 3G S or faster devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472278/how-do-i-make-my-application-available-on-the-app-store-only-for-iphone-3g-s-or)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319371/iphone-4-only-app and also stackoverflow.com/questions/3283189/can-i-restrict-my-iphone-app-from-being-used-by-iphone3gs

Comment: I think that this case very different from all 3g answers because 3gs has armv7 and opengles-2.0 support therefore is not possible easy avoid it by UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities

Comment: Hm, might be 'front-facing-camera' key is an solution for this case.