# Exclude IPhone 3GS from App (Adobe Air)

Tags: iphone, ios, air, app-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I restrict my iPhone app from being used by iPhone3G’s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283189/can-i-restrict-my-iphone-app-from-being-used-by-iphone3gs)

I have build an application for IOS and it runs fine on IPhone 4 (and above) and all IPads.
Just the 3GS seens to lack power to run it well. Can i exclude the app for these devices?

I have found using UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities and http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html to limit apps using required Capabilities. But i can not find something to just exclude the 3GS. Does anyone know ?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, I think, you quote the wrong link. That question is about iPhone 3G and not iPhone 3GS.

Comment: it is not a duplicate as this is for 3GS while the possible duplicate is for 3G

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key to info.plist file and `front-facing-camera` as required value. If I am correct, 3GS doesn't have a front camera. Here is the [apple documentation with all possible values](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3). As mentioned by  TonyMkenu in comments, check this link [for UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities and Device Compatibility Matrix](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/10/30/uirequireddevicecapabilities-and-device-compatibility-matrix)

Comment: You are correct, I own a 3GS and it doesn't have one.

Comment: do all other IPhones (4 and above) have font facing cameras ? What will Apple say to this kind of hack?

Comment: UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities and Device Compatibility Matrix: http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/10/30/uirequireddevicecapabilities-and-device-compatibility-matrix

Comment: @TobiHeidi, This is not a hack. It is provided by Apple to make sure that the app will not run in a device which doesnt have this feature. You just can use it in your case as well. And yes, all iPhones from 4 and above has front facing cameras. You can confirm it by just googling for the iPhone devices and features.

Comment: There is no "kind of hack" :) ..Is in Apple documentation, dude :)

Comment: @TonyMkenu, Thanks for that link. I have added that in answer. :)

Comment: But my app will not use a front facing camera, so it is kind of a "workaround" at least. Has any one used this and got approved by apple?