# I only want my app to support the iPhone 5 and iPod touch 5th gen how do I set it so it won't be allowed for download by other devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

The app I created is only designed to support the iPhone 5 and iPod touch 5th Gen because of their resolution. How do I set it up so that it can only be downloaded and be installed on iPhone5s or iPod Touch 5th gen devices? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3283386/869455)

Apple Appstore has no such feature as on Android Market to filter devices on which app can be downloaded. However you can specify required device capabilities in info.plist by using UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key. You can find possible values in [this Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html)

Comment: Just like how there are some apps on the appstore that are designed only for the new (4-inch) resolution devices. I'm trying to not allow people with the old resolution devices to download the app because it wasn't designed for them. How do I use UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities for this?

Comment: There are apps on appstore which are 'optimized' for iPhone5. This means that they will run on iPhone5 as good as on older 3.5 inch device.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @Atif 's answer. you can see device capabilities on the Device compatibility matrix that is found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH17-SW1