# Can we restrict download or launch of an universal app in iPad 1 alone?

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, ios-universal-app

I have a universal app, it supports both iPad and iPhone. I do not want the app to be downloaded or launched in iPad 1 alone.

When the user downloads the app from App Store, is there a way to disable the download or launch of the app only for the first generation of iPad.

If not, can I add it in "What's new" option during the release of the app to App Store. Since it is a next version of release.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283189/can-i-restrict-my-iphone-app-from-being-used-by-iphone3gs

Comment: Someone had done something retarded with their updated version, putting a WARNING in their app description, saying that the update is for iPhone 5 only, do not download it if you have iPhone 4/4s! That's the last solution I'd go with, but eh! Users take it easy these days, many don't care!

Answer (score 2):

You could try to find a restriction with the **UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities** key in the info.plist. But this key only allows restrictions like armv7, magnetometer, etc. (full list available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3)). So you can't filter only iPads of the first generation.

Anyway, what you could do is checking at runtime whether it's an iPad 1 or not.
With this [Library](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension) it's quite simple:

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] platformType] == UIDevice1GiPad){
   //it's an iPad 1!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can restrict your software to a certain class of devices, but you can impose limits based on iOS version. The newest version of iOS supported by the original iPad is 5.1.1, which is quite dated now, so you might consider requiring iOS6+ on the App Store.

Also, you could require the device to have a camera, which the iPad 1 does not. But beware that Apple could reject your app if it does not actually use the camera.

Comment: There could be iPhone's and iPod Touch still running iOS 4 and above; numbers are very low though. I agree with your second point.

Comment: iOS 4!!!! Number would in very very small. Seeing as how 98% are on iOS 7 ? the rest on 6. As a developer I don't support further back than 7. I appreciate some people want to (need to) do the extra work required to support 6+7. But 4/5/6 & 7, why ?! surely not cost effective.

Answer (score 0):

Best possible way is to give the support for iOS 6+ which will exclude the ipad first generation.