# iTunes Connect asking screen shots for project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I've developed an app for iPhone (Portrait orientation) and with iOS 8.0. I checked that every single one of the Views are set for size of 4 inches. (I want to target iPhones 5, 5C and 5S).

Probably this is a very noob question, but I'm trying to submit an app into the itunes connect, but when I want to submit, the system replies that I need submit screen shots for 5.5 inches retina, 3.5 inches and 4.7 inches.

How do I correct this issue?, because even iPod is allowed to use my app in this moment.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the app in the simulator under every device screen size (E.g. iPhone 4, 5, 6, 6+) and for every screen, save the screen shot via `Command-S`.

That is because your app is naturally optimized for the iPhone 6+. Therefore from [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html),

> If your app indicates that it is optimized for the iPhone 6 Plus, at
>   least one 5.5-inch screenshot is required. Up to four additional
>   screenshots can be uploaded. You can rearrange the screenshots when
>   you create or edit the iTunes Connect record.

along with the fact that 4 and 3.5 inch screenshots are required.

Comment: Hi Nate.
Ty for your reply. 
How can I set my app only for iPhones 5 series?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891277/how-to-disable-iphone-6-native-resolution already has a good answer for that, but basically he states to remove your `launch screen XIB` and any other screenshot for the iPhone 6/6+. You will also have to "go to General, and under "Launch Screen File" blank out the entry," and clean the project.

Comment: @Kragan It's not possible to prohibit certain devices, but it is possible to require certain features only present on new devices. Take a look at this SO thread for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283189/can-i-restrict-my-iphone-app-from-being-used-by-iphone3gs/3283386#3283386